# adding Hyperlink in win app

Tags: c#, winforms, hyperlink

I'm looking for a way to use hyperlinks in a winforms environment.

I found that it uses `System.Web.UI.WebControls`; but when i tried to use it in my program `System.Web` was as far as it would go.
So I checked the refrences but also no `System.Web.UI.WebControls` or something like that,
any sugestions?

Comment: There are two ways to use hyperlinks - one to open a link in the users default browser (i.e. a separate process), the other is to have a web browser control in your application. Which is your scenario?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.linklabel.aspx

Comment: Do you want "real" hyperlinks that open a web page in an external browser, or just buttons that look like hyperlinks for navigating arround your application?

Comment: The  senario is as follows: i want a hyperlink in a richtexbox, would rather do i with link labels bu that is a no go... the rest of the manipulation i can do whith events

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your're developing a WinForms application you have to use `System.Windows.Forms.LinkLabel` control, located in `System.Windows.Forms` assembly. Controls in `System.Web.*` are for HTML pages.

Answer (score 10):

You can use LinkLabel control. Set text property of LinkLabel to show your web link. You can use "LinkClicked" event to open the web browser as shown below. Hope this helps you.

```
     private void linkLabel1_LinkClicked(object sender, LinkLabelLinkClickedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(linkLabel1.Text);
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

[image: Why dont you use Link Label]

Comment: Would've been better just linking to MSDN like the others

Answer (score -1):

If it's `WPF` you can do something like this:

```
<TextBlock>           
    <Hyperlink NavigateUri="http://www.google.com" RequestNavigate="Hyperlink_RequestNavigate">
        Click here
    </Hyperlink>
</TextBlock>
```

And in the code-behind:

```
private void Hyperlink_RequestNavigate(object sender, RequestNavigateEventArgs e)
{
    Process.Start(new ProcessStartInfo(e.Uri.AbsoluteUri));
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

It will look like this:

[image: oO]